# AngularJS: how do I show ellipses using limitTo filter only when a string exceeds the limit

Tags: angularjs, string, filter

I am using the limitTo filter on some strings. If the string is less than, say, 10 characters, then the string is displayed as is. If the string is longer than 10 characters, I want to display ellipses after cutting off the string at the tenth character. Is there an angular shortcut to doing this? Thanks

for example:

```
{{main.title | limitTo:10}}
```

if main.title = "A Good Day", the output would be: A Good Day

if main.title = "A Terrible Day", the output would be: A Terrible...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Well, if you want you can build a filter for this, but I would use `ngIf` directive, as below:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function() {
      var vm = this;

      vm.text = 'Really longer than 10';
    });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl as ctrl">
  Without limit: <span ng-bind="ctrl.text"></span>
  <hr>
  With limit: <span ng-bind="ctrl.text | limitTo:10"></span>
  <span ng-if="ctrl.text.length > 10">...</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: great. thanks for your help. Answer was obvious but it went over me.

Answer (score 41):

Hope this helps :

```
{{ main.title | limitTo: 10 }}{{main.title.length > 10 ? '...' : ''}}
```

Comment: I like this answer much better than using another span with ng-if, thanks

Comment: This was quick, easy to understand, and worked perfectly for what I needed.

Comment: I would suggest using the HTML ellipsis: `&#8230;`

Answer (score 5):

Writing your own filter based on `limitTo` is the best way to do this.

```
angular.module('your-module-name').filter('dotsFilter', [
    '$filter',
    function ($filter) {
        /**
         * Shorten the input and add dots if it's needed
         * @param {string} input 
         * @param {number} limit
         */
        function dotsFilter(input, limit) {
            var newContent = $filter('limitTo')(input, limit);
            if(newContent.length < input.length) { newContent += '...'; }
            return newContent;
        }

        return dotsFilter;
    }
]);
```

Use in view:

```
{{ model.longTextData | dotsFilter:10 }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `<span ng-class="{'ellipsis': text.length > limit}">{{text | limitTo:limit}}</span>`

You need to define a css class `.ellipsis:after{ content: '...'; }` and a scope variable `limit`

**OR**

```
{{ text.length > limit ? ((text | limitTo:limit) + "...") : text }}
```

```js
(function() {
      "use strict";
      angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.text = "Hello World";
          $scope.limit = 10;
        });
    })();
```

```css
.ellipsis:after{ content: '...'; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="app">

    <head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
      <h3>Using Option1</h3>
      <span ng-class="{'ellipsis': text.length > limit}">{{ text | limitTo:limit }}</span>
      <br>
      <h3>Using Option2</h3>
      <span>{{ text.length > limit ? ((text | limitTo:limit) + "...") : text }}</span>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: This is nice and simple and you can do `limitTo:limit-3`, unlike with BeingSuman's answer, which might add an elipsis for a single character.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers using angularjs are already posted, I'm gonna give you a simple css technique to do it.

```js
   (function() {
      "use strict";
      angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book";
        });
    })();
```

```css
span.ellipsis {
    display:inline-block;
    width:180px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="app">

    <head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
      <span ng:class="{true:'ellipsis', false:''}[text.length>=10]" style="max-width: 10ch;">{{text}}</span>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: How are you limiting the number of characters?

Comment: I've updated my answer according the requirements, Please see if it works for you

Comment: span.ellipsis:after {
    content: '...'
}

Comment: You shouldn't need the inline-block (that's just because it's a span and so  is inline not inline-block) and the !important isn't generally needed

Answer (score 1):

Someone reading in the future may consider using CSS instead of JS. Something like:

```
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: I agree it's the best solution :) Where you don't need to use JS, it's better not to use it

Answer (score 1):

```
<div maxlength="59"> 
  {{row.RequestTitle.length > 59 ? row.RequestTitle.substr(0,59) + '...' : row.RequestTitle}} 
</div>
```

this is usefull and run also , Angular 5 Material UI

Comment: Please indent code blocks with 4 spaces instead of using bold formatting. Code blocks (full ones with 4 spaces or inline with backticks) also allow HTML tags without formatting them as a part of the post.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to use ellipsis logic in controller then the following code snippet will be helpful:

```
$filter('limitTo')(input, limit) + (input.length > limit ? '&hellip;' : '');
```

Where `input` and `limit` will be the 'input string' and the numeric limit value, e.g.

```
$filter('limitTo')(stringText, 20) + (stringText.length > 20 ? '&hellip;' : '');
```